# Java pause GUI from inside ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I've made a GUI that displays 9 playing cards and 1 button. On button press, 3 random cards should change background color, then after pausing a second, the cards should revert back to their original color. The trouble comes with pausing the GUI while their color is changed. I tried Thread.sleep() but that only pauses the main thread.  I've seen posts that point to the Timer class, but as this would need to be handled inside the ActionListener block I don't think it's what I'm looking for. I've successfully written methods to choose random cards and change their colors; I'm looking for a way to either freeze a GUI screen or a JPanel within it.

```
myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        Card[] cards = selectThree();
        highlightBorders(cards, Color.RED);
        //**THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO PAUSE FOR A SECOND**
        highlightBorders(cards, Color.WHITE);
```

Comment: You should use something like Timer and from within it, call SwingUtilities.invokeLater(... runnable which changes color...)

Comment: @ArturBiesiadowski: specifically, use a javax.swing.Timer or "Swing Timer" ([tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)). With this, there's no need to queue code on the EDT since all calls within this timer are run on the EDT.

Comment: Use a javax.swing.Timer, set it to not repeat, and in the ActionListener of the Timer make the call to `highlightBorders(cards, Color.WHITE);`

Comment: For example: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/WbqSjvCR)

Comment: For future reference, you can easily search this site using either its own search engine or Google's and quickly find the answer you need. For example, this Google search on this site: [site:stackoverflow.com java pause a swing gui](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+pause+a+swing+gui), quickly brought up many similar questions, some with high quality answers that could easily have solved your problem.

Comment: it worked, thank you!